# get all entries from a nested has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails model with a has_many association

```
Class Car
has_many parts
```

and a second one on part model

```
Class Part
has_many prices
```

I have a specific car instance

```
myCar = Car.find 5
```

I want to get all prices for that instance

```
myCar.all_prices
```

Comment: Can you post you database schema of these three tables?

Comment: May we have some feedback on the answers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you wanna get `prices`, thus, let keep it as the target when writing your query. Below query will work

```
Price.joins(part: :car).where(cars: { id: 5 })
```

It generates SQL as below

```
SELECT  `prices`.* FROM `prices` INNER JOIN `parts` ON `parts`.`id` = `prices`.`part_id` INNER JOIN `cars` ON `cars`.`id` = `parts`.`car_id` WHERE `cars`.`id` = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define it like this :

```
Class Car < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :parts
  has_many :prices, through: :parts
end

Class Part < ApplicationRecord
  belong_to :car
  has_many  :prices
end
```

then you can do :

```
myCar = Car.find 5
myCar.prices
```

Reference : https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Answer (score 0):

`myCar = Car.find 5`

`myCar.parts.collect(&:prices)`

`myCar.parts.includes(:prices).collect(&:prices)` - for eager loading

Here we are finding the parts form the car object and then iterating each parts(with collect method of ruby) and returning its prices.

`myCar.parts.collect{ |part| part.prices }` is same as above.

Comment: I have edited/explained the post. 
Basically we are just iterating each objects to get its child.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `Price.column_names`, but let's suppose there is a column `value` in `Price`, you should be able to do this in just one query:

```
Car.joins(parts: :prices).where(cars: {id: 5}).select('prices.value')#.map(&:value)
```

This uses [active_record_querying#joining-tables](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables)

Even better (more complete):

```
Car.joins(parts: :prices)
   .where(cars: {id: 5})
   .select('cars.name AS car_name, prices.value AS part_price, parts.name AS part_name')
  #.map{ |e| [e.car_name, e.part_name, e.part_price] }
```